# How to remove empty string properties from json using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to omit empty string properties from my Json.

Here's what I did.

Create a Custom Converter that converts empty strings to null:

```
public class EmptyStringToNullConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == string.Empty)
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        else
            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

I have a `JsonSerializerClass`, which basically is a wrapper around `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` and this class is using the Converter:

```
    public class JsonSerializerClass
{
    private JsonSerializerOptions serializeOptions;
    private JsonSerializerOptions deserializeOptions;

    public JsonSerializerClass()
    {
        serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        deserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        InitSerializer();
        InitDeserializer();
    }

    public JsonSerializerOptions SerializeOptions => serializeOptions;

    public string Serialize(object value)
    {
        return Serialize(value, serializeOptions);
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        var o = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, deserializeOptions);

        if (o == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot deserialize JSON to type {typeof(T)}: {json}");

        return o;
    }

    public static string Serialize(object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options);
    }

    private void InitSerializer()
    {
        serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringToNullConverter());

        serializeOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    }

    private void InitDeserializer()
    {
        deserializeOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;

        deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyConverter());
        deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyNullableConverter());
        deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new IntConverter());
        deserializeOptions.Converters.Add(new DecimalConverter());

        deserializeOptions.IncludeFields = true;
        deserializeOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
        deserializeOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
        deserializeOptions.ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip;
    }
}
```

And here's my test case:

```
var person = new Person
{
    Name = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    MiddleName = ""
};
var serializer = new JsonSerializerClass();

var json = serializer.Serialize(person);

json.ToLower().Should().NotContain(nameof(person.MiddleName).ToLower());
```

I would expect that `MiddleName` is not in the json because empty string becomes null and null values should be removed from the json. But instead `MiddleName` is in the json, with value `null`!

Comment: I think you missed setting IgnoreNullValues to true on your deserializeOptions instance. Besides that can't say i like handling empty strings like null but that's up to you. Oh my bad that one seems to be obsolete now.

Comment: I guess, a converter is too late. You probably need this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers Because just writing nothing at all will disrupt the json: https://dotnetfiddle.net/layxIO

Comment: Different guess i would assume the Option prevents that a JsonConverter writes anything but your custom JsonConverter takes the option but then ignores it and always calls writer.WriteNullValue();

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 7, you can use a [Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to influence the serialization process (more information in the [announcement blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/)):

```cs
static void ExcludeEmptyStrings(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
{
    if (jsonTypeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
        return;

    foreach (JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo in jsonTypeInfo.Properties)
    {
        if (jsonPropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            jsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, it's all about the [`ShouldSerialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.shouldserialize?view=net-7.0) property, which takes in the `value` and allows you to decide whether or not it should be serialized.

Add the modifier using the property I linked above:

```
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { ExcludeEmptyStrings }
    }
};
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EC4uR)

Comment: Yes, I came across this too, but I'm using ,net core 6...

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that could be the case, but I didn't see any mention of .NET 6 in your question.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can try this custom converter

```
    var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
    options.Converters.Add(new IgnoreNullOrEmptyStringJsonConverter<Person>());
    var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(person, options);

public class IgnoreNullOrEmptyStringJsonConverter<T> : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<T> where T : class
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Use default implementation when deserializing (reading)
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        using (JsonDocument document = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument(value))
        {
            foreach (var property in document.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                if (property.Value.ValueKind.ToString() != "Null" 
                   && !(property.Value.ValueKind.ToString() == "String" 
                   && string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.Value.ToString())))
                    property.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

output

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe"
}
```

or you can use this function

```
    var json = GetIgnoreNullOrEmptyStringJson(person);


public string GetIgnoreNullOrEmptyStringJson<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    var jNode = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(value);

    var props = jNode.AsObject()
        .Where(prop => (prop.Value == null
               || (prop.Value.GetValue<JsonElement>().ValueKind.ToString() == "String"
               && string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.Value.ToString()))))
        .Select(e => e)
        .ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        jNode.AsObject().Remove(props[i].Key);

    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jNode, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but now I get `"MiddleName": {},`

I think it isn't possible with Conververts.. It seems like Converters are applied very late in the serialization process.

Comment: @Martijn  As you understand this code was tested and working properly. See my output